# Polynomial function $ f(x)= e^x + 1 - 5 \sqrt x $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, definition

$ f(x)= e^x + 1 - 5 \sqrt x $ is this a polynomial function? As I am not quite sure if $e^x$ can be in a polynomial function.

Comment: No, $\mathrm e^x$ is a transcendental function.

Comment: I'd say no, but so I would say of $\sqrt x$ which, on the other hand, does not seem to faze you.

Comment: So what type of function is it then? a transcendental function?

Comment: What do you mean by a "type" of a function?

Comment: @Gae.S., this requires a proof though. For example, $\sqrt{x^4}\sin\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x^2\cos\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ is a polynomial function.

Comment: I want to prove that this equation has at least one solution in the
interval (1, 2). But i am not sure of how to do it if this is not a polynomial function.

Comment: What does the question of having zeros in $(1,2)$ have to do with polynomial functions?

Comment: @Alexey Obviously, just like $e^x-e^x$ is polynomial, for that matter. The fact is that I don't like the idea of attempting a proof if the definition is not clear to me. For instance, the definition I have in mind also has $\sqrt x$ non-polynomial, but that does not seem to concern the OP.

Comment: @Gae.S., sorry, the definition of what is not clear to you?

Comment: @Alexey Polynomial function, in the very specific meaning that the OP is using right now.

Comment: @Gae.S., well, then you should better not comment on this question. I imagine there should be a definition in Wikipedia. If not, here it is: it is a function of the form $x\mapsto P(x)$, where $P$ is a polynomial. I have never heard of a "very specific" meaning of of a polynomial function that would be different from the usual one.

Comment: @alexey if this was a polynomial functions i could put the interval (1,2) in x place and find out if there is a solution.

Comment: @Alexey I think I'll do whatever the hell I want, thank you.

Comment: @Tom, sorry i do not get you. I suggest you check the properties of continuous functions.

Comment: @Tom, If you want to show that the equation $f(x)=0$ has at least one solution in the interval $(1,2)$, you need to know that the function is *continuous* (which it is), not that it's a polynomial (which it isn't).

Comment: @barrycipra thank you very much, that was exactly what i was looking to finde out :)

Comment: @Tom, you are entirely welcome. You may be pleased to know that the question you inadvertently asked is in itself quite interesting: The proofs that functions like $e^x$ and $\sqrt x$ (much less some combination of them) are not polynomials are actually fairly subtle.

Comment: @Alexey, your example with the sine and cosine of $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ doesn't look polynomial to me.

Comment: @BarryCipra, thanks, my fault, i meant $\sqrt{x^4}\sin^2\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x^2\cos^2\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$.

Comment: @Alexey, ah, yes, of course!

Comment: I'm kind of curious as to why you're doing stuff with $e^x$, if this is supposed to be pre-calculus. But FWIW, this function has a zero near $x=0.2$ & another near $x=1.7$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

- The function $e^x$ by itself is not a polynomial function; there's no way to rewrite it as a polynomial. You can find different ways of explaining or proving *why* it can't be rewritten as a polynomial; you can also just remember and recognize this feature of $e^x$.
- The function $\sqrt{x}$ is also not a polynomial function.
- What happens when you combine polynomial and non-polynomial functions together? If you add or multiply them together, then you can *usually* expect the combination will be **non-polynomial**. (It will be non-polynomial unless some of the non-polynomial components cancel each other out.) It is as if the non-polynomial functions "contaminate" the combined function and make it non-polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

If $h(x)=e^x$ is a polinomial of degree $n$, then $h^{(n+1)}(x)=0$.

This is not true because $h^{(n)}(x)=e^x$, for any $n$.

Ps.: $h^{(n)}(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $h$.

Answer (score 0):

All polynomial functions are of the form $P(x) = a_{n}x^{n} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +...+a_{1}x + a_{0}$, with $n$ a finite nonnegative real number and each $a_{i}$ constant. Thus, $h(x)$ is not a polynomial because it contains $e^{x}$, a transcedental function that cannot be represented as a polynomial, as well as $\sqrt{x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: As pointed out in the comments above that is not quite sufficient. For example $\cos(e^x+\sqrt{x})^2+\sin(e^x+\sqrt{x})^2$ "contains" transcendental functions, nonetheless it is a polynomial function (on a suitable domain).